# Popup window with Maximize & close,Resize options

Tags: asp.net

I am looking  for a popup window which will have Minimize(Optional), Maximize & close,Resize options. Is there any link available where i can find it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this... you can set the features you want to yes or no.

```
window.open('URL','Help','width=802,height=554,menubar=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes')
```